# Retrieving links using jquery

Tags: jquery, getjson

I'm trying to create a list links using jquery. I'm using this code to retreive the date

```
$.getJSON('/chapersRetrival.php', function(data) 
        {
            $.each(data, function(index, array) {    
            $("<a/>").attr({href: 'http://www.mangamanga.com/chapNo='+array['chapterID']+'&#pageNo=1>', title:array['mangaName'] + array['chapterName']} + array['chapterNumber']).appendTo("#mangaChpaters"); 
            });
        });
```

just wondering if there is anything wrong with regards to who the code is written ?

Comment: This bit looks suspicious: `&#pageNo=1>` Are you intending that to be a query parameter (then remove the `#`), or a `location.hash` (then remove the `&`). Also, the right angle bracket looks out of place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a closing `}` too soon.  In needs to come after your concatenation of `array['chapterNumber']`. Otherwise it looks fine to me.

The fix:

```
$.getJSON('/chapersRetrival.php', function(data) 
        {
            $.each(data, function(index, array) {    
                $("<a/>").attr({href: 'http://www.mangamanga.com/chapNo='+array['chapterID']+'&#pageNo=1>', title:array['mangaName'] + array['chapterName'] + array['chapterNumber']}).appendTo("#mangaChpaters"); 
            });
});
```

Comment: He's not trying to *select* all anchors, he's trying to *create* an anchor - right at the end he's appending the newly minted anchor to `#mangaChpaters` [sic]. The syntax for element creation is to pass a HTML string to the jQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

Well for a start, you can make it much more readable by adding some line breaks. Also, the `this` pointer can be used as a shorthand inside the function to point to the current piece of data:

```
$.getJSON('/chapersRetrival.php', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function() {    
        $("<a/>").attr({
            href: 'http://www.mangamanga.com/chapNo='+this['chapterID']+'&#pageNo=1>',
            title: this['mangaName'] + this['chapterName'] + this['chapterNumber']
        }).appendTo("#mangaChpaters"); 
    });
});
```

Also, you seem to have made a couple of spelling mistakes/typos, which have been "fixed" here:

```
$.getJSON('/chaptersRetrieval.php', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function() {    
        $("<a/>").attr({
            href: 'http://www.mangamanga.com/chapNo='+this['chapterID']+'#pageNo=1',
            title: this['mangaName'] + this['chapterName'] + this['chapterNumber']
        }).appendTo("#mangaChapters"); 
    });
});
```